# Printing sql query results

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Two separate but related questions to querying a database and sending the results to discord:

Example code:

```
async def query(ctx):
try:
    cursor.execute("SELECT record.name, COUNT(place.name) .....")
        for row in cursor:
        await ctx.send(row)
except Error as e:
     print(e)
```

Each row prints as it's own message and displays in the following format:

```
('potato', 1)
('orange', 1)
('steak', 1)
```

I would like to append all the rows into a single message as the results are numerous enough that this blows the channel up with spam messages. Each row on it's own line and part 2, remove the query result formatting.

It should look like this(parentheses indicating one message not visible formatting):

```
"
potato 1
orange 2
steak 1
"
```

I have tried to change "await ctx.send(row)" to "await ctx.send(row[0],row[1]) to remove the formatting but I know send doesn't operate in the same manner as print() and it's instead looking for a string.
"await ctx.send(row[0].join(row[1]))" fails because: "TypeError: can only join an iterable"

Further I have no clue how to get the result from cursor append it into a single string with line breaks.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic python

```py
message = ""
for veg, i in cursor.fetchall(): # Or however you named it
    message += f"{veg} {i}\n"
```

The message var now looks like this:

```
"potato 1
orange 2
steak 1"
```

Comment: "    for veg, i in cursor:ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" I've gone this route and always get this. In looking into this route further I've seen suggesting using split to split the cursor results and other sources treating the cursor results as an array.

Comment: From the code you provided, I don't know how exactly does the list look, I'm assuming it looks something like this `[("orange", 1), ("banana", 2), ...]`, If that's not the case, please, edit your question and add it